# ReactJS: Map array of images with unique pop up per image

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, popup, gatsby

I'm new to React & really stuck on how to create a popup which is unique to each image.

I have 20 images, which all need to be clickable with a unique pop up (only one pop up at a time open).

I am mapping out the images from an array. Can anyone help me with creating a pop up per image? The pop up must contain text and an image.

```html
        <div className={divStyle}>
          {finalBoxArray.map(gooseberry => (
            <Img
              key={allPlaces.infoid}
              className={gooseberryStyle}
              alt="gooseberry"
              fixed={about.fixed}
              style={{
                top: gooseberry.top,
                left: gooseberry.left
              }}
            />
          ))}
          
          
 array is as below:
 const allPlaces = [
  {
    infoid: 'box1',
    top: '145px',
    left: '935px',
    found: false,
  },
  {
    infoid: 'box2',
    top: '120px',
    left: '980px',
    found: false
  },  
  {
    infoid: 'box3',
    top: '560px',
    left: '450px',
    found: false
  },
  {
    infoid: 'box4',
    top: '380px',
    left: '760px',
    found: false
  },
  {
    infoid: 'box5',
    top: '460px',
    left: '600px',
    found: false
  },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not quite complete and not very clear to me.
But from what I understand, you're trying to create an array of images with different styles. If so, then you need to create an array to actually hold your images and map an image element to your allPlaces array. Here's an edit:

```js
/* I'm not quite sure if you have a custom 
* Img element you created because you wrote it like 
* <Img/> instead of <img/>
*/

const imgArray = allPlaces.map((obj) => {
  <img
    key={obj.infoid}
    className={gooseberryStyle}
    alt="gooseberry"
    fixed={obj.fixed}
    style={{
      top: obj.top,
      left: obj.left
    }} />
});

//add the array to the div container and render
<div className={divStyle} >
  {imgArray}
</div>
          
array is as below:
const allPlaces = [
{
  infoid: 'box1',
  top: '145px',
  left: '935px',
  found: false,
},
{
  infoid: 'box2',
  top: '120px',
  left: '980px',
  found: false
},  
{
  infoid: 'box3',
  top: '560px',
  left: '450px',
  found: false
},]
```